# All indicators start blinking when I plug in my Lenovo laptop

Tags: power-supply, battery, lenovo-laptop

I have a Lenovo S400. Recently, this weird behavior started. When I plug it in, all the indicators, power LED, charging LED (blinks red) and power button start blinking together.
It seems like a danger indicator to me. What does it mean? I suspect a problem with the power adapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It indicates a damaged battery, or that it doesn't have enough charge.

Some have reported that the battery is not charging but this can be fixed on the machine (if you can get to it), so the following may or may not apply to you.

> 1. Disconnect the A/C power supply.
> 2. Shut down the computer.
> 3. Remove the battery
> 4. Connect the A/C power supply
> 5. Start the computer.
> 6. Under Battery... (here's the problem, Jeff--where is "battery?" I searched, and finally remembered it is under Control Panel, then
>      System, then Device Driver, then Battery)
> 7. Click on Battery (at the top), and then right click on all entries that say Microsoft ACPI Compliant Control Method Battery, and select
>      uninstall.
> 8. Shut the computer down.
> 9. Disconnect the A/C power supply.
> 10. Insert the battery.
> 11. Insert the A/C power supply.
> 12. Start the computer.

[Source](http://offthewallchina.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/lenovo-plugged-in-not-charging-battery.html)